# Why wont my bootstrap DateTimePicker work?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have used this in another MVC project of mine and the code works perfect when I run that program. I'm trying to use it in my new MVC application now and I cant get it to work with the same code. I've added all of the references to jQuery and bootstrap.

The text box shows up fine, along with the glyphicon for the datetimepicker and when I hover over it the mouse changes into the hand symbol. When I click the button nothing happens at that point. Here is what my code looks like for the datetimepicker:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InterviewDate, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InterviewDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    //$('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    //    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
                    //});
                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                });

            </script>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My _Layout page references these at the top:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title Job Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin-top: 60px;
            background: #d9edf7;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

And then references these at the bottom:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", false)
```

If I'm forgetting anything or you need more information please let me know. I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: have u check your console? if not, press f12 and check if there is any error?

Comment: Your duplicating scripts. Remove them from the head and check your bundles. Any scripts that you use that are not in the bundles, either create a new bundle or add then at the bottom in the correct order

Comment: Wow, that double reference fixed it. Thank you for noticing that... it was one of those things I was staring at for hours and took a second to fix! I appreciate it.